# add Alfresco 5 repository as external liferay 6.2 repository

Tags: liferay, alfresco, cmis

I would use Alfresco repository from my liferay system. 
I used this info [Liferay wiki about CMIS repository integration](https://www.liferay.com/en/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/CMIS+Repository)

Both Liferay and Alfresco using the same LDAP.
I create in my liferay a custom Document and media portlet that show external Alfresco repository.
But id logout as admin and login as user, the portlet don't show the external repository. 
Furthermore after some log-in and log-out also admin is unable to see external repository and the portlet (that must show alfresco User Home folder) now show thie error: **The folder could not be found**. 
I see in Liferay logs error like

```
 No channel exists with user id 11439
```

or like

```
08:59:01,255 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-15][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
com.liferay.portal.NoSuchRepositoryEntryException: No RepositoryEntry exists with the primary key 14723
        at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.RepositoryEntryPersistenceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(RepositoryEntryPersistenceImpl.java:2678)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.RepositoryEntryPersistenceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(RepositoryEntryPersistenceImpl.java:2696)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.RepositoryLocalServiceImpl.createRepositoryImpl(RepositoryLocalServiceImpl.java:418)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.RepositoryLocalServiceImpl.getRepositoryImpl(RepositoryLocalServiceImpl.java:367)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryImpl(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:140)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLAppServiceImpl.getFolderRepository(DLAppServiceImpl.java:3412)
```

Also if I restart both system error persist.
I can create external repository again... but after some login logout I have the same problem again!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pheraps this could help you: [Liferay Forum](https://www.liferay.com/it/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/49296368)